# Why wasn't the Oral law imbedded in the Written?

Tags: oral-torah, written-torah

Why were the Mishnah or the Gemara not included in the 5 books of Moshe Rabbeinu? Why was the system made in such a way that, we the people, had to go dig up and find out for ourselves?

What wasn't Mishna Berachot somehow placed in one of the 5 books. If the MIshnah was going to be revealed eventually anyway, why wasn't it put in the Written Torah to begin with?

I guess, what I am asking is why didn't G_d give the Mishnah,Gemara etc., as one packaged deal along with the 5 books of the Chumash?

Comment: There is only one revelation which was on Mt. Sinai. The teachings from there at that time was known to all who were there, as taught by Moses, Aaron, and the Elders. These traditions we are exposed to today are only part of the entire knowledge ever toiled and attained throughout centuries. Secondly, there ARE moments in the Torah where the Oral Law is hinted to. An example is Genesis 7:2, how would Noah know which are the 'clean' and 'unclean' animals delineated by Torah? It must have been that God told him, taught him, guided him. Therefore those are oral torah = oral intrustions

Comment: I answered this in passing, here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/132105/31534. If you want to hear more about the point, lmk

Comment: Duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67621/god-created-both-the-written-law-and-the-oral-before-the-world-was-created-why?rq=1

Comment: The laws of the Mishnah were transmitted orally to ensure maximum clarity. They were only written down when the Rabbis saw that due to persecution, this method could not last.